# how to remove a class using dom in php?

Tags: php, dom

i want to remove the class "refs" that includes references. the page(http://www.sacred-destinations.com/mexico/palenque) from where i m getting the content looks like:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7" id="essay">
    <section class="refs">
    </section>
    </div><!-- end #essay -->
```

now i am not getting how to remove this 'refs' class as it is enclosed in "section" like something..
here is something that i have done so far...

```
<?php
$url="http://www.sacred-destinations.com/mexico/palenque";
 $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $newDom = new domDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $newDom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $newDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $newDom->validateOnParse = true;
    $sections = $newDom->saveHTML($newDom->getElementById('essay'));
$text=$sections->find('<section class="refs">');
$result=removeClass($text);
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMDocument has no find() method, you have to use DOMXPath::evaluate() with XPath expressions.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$expression = 
  '//div[
     @id="essay"
   ]
   /section[
     contains(
       concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " refs "
     )
   ]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $section) {  
  $section->removeAttribute('class');
}
echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

Class attributes can contain multiple values like `classOne classTwo`. With `normalize-space()` the whitespaces will be reduced to single spaces inside the string (start and end removed). `concat()` add spaces to the start and end. This avoid matching the class name as part of another class name.

In the example the whole class attribute will be removed. To modify it you can read it with DOMElement::getAttribute() and use string functions to change it.

Here are several DOM based libraries that can make HTML manipulation easier.

Comment: the class is not removed..still 'refs' class is appearing in the output...:|

Comment: there is still problem in your code...i have tried but couldnt fix it.. can you please fix it

Comment: The source removes the class attribute, the demo shows that. Requests with curl are a different topic, and you did not ask about that part. Validate if that part works. If not, try to debug it. After you get the HTML you can edit it. At the moment you just say it doesn't work. I can't help without a real error description.