# How to add class name to an existing tag in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a hidden tag in HTML:

```html
<p class="class1">something<p>
```

and PHP code:

```php
if(SomeCondition){
 select element by DOM and add class "active" so that element will be shown
}
```

How can I select an element by DOM specifically in this PHP file and perform operations on this element, for example, add class or remove class or change its properties (e.g.: bg color: black).

P.S. SomeCondition is server-sided

Comment: Have you tried anything with domdocument yet? "change its properties" would vary by the attribute you want to change. e.g. `style` vs. `bgcolor` Possible dup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117443/how-to-remove-a-class-using-dom-in-php

Comment: `if(SomeCondition){` is being determined based on the user actions?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to change the attributes (class) server side (in this case you can use php) or client side (then that's a javascript thing)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you are parsing HTML in PHP and based on something there you will add/remove a class? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117443/how-to-remove-a-class-using-dom-in-php already?

Comment: Does it have to be that complicated? i cannot understand 70% of the code written in that question (libxml_use_internal_errors,curl_setopt etc.)

Comment: @Sema Unclear if it does or doesn't. The question doesn't show where the HTML code is. If it is in a PHP variable already then you don't need to do anything with CURL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it in PHP that way. I mean not in a simple way. This is done in JS / jQuery, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $(".class1").addClass("active"); 
});
```

Comment: it does not attempt to answer the OP question. There might be reasons he want to do it with PHP instead JS or jQery which is user-sided while PHP does this server sided.

Comment: The OP did not specify the problem. Maybe he doesn't know a better way to do what he needs?

Comment: Then ask for clarification first instead of posting a vague guess that is soley based on thinking that the OP doesnt know what he ask for.

Comment: I would write it in a comment if I could comment the question.

Comment: My bad, sorry for not specifying my question. I am new to such platforms as stackoverflow. I appreciate your help in any way. Condition is server-sided.

Answer (score 0):

Laid out for clarity and for proving it works.  The solution is for executing server side as the condition is on the server.

```php
<?php
$Condition = false;
if ($Condition)
   {$class='active';}
else
   {$class='hidden';}
?>
<p class="class1 <?php echo $class;?>">something</p>
```

The **<p>** element then has the class of either `class1 active` or `class1 hidden`.

Obviously, $Condition is probably an expression!